# it is possible to insert or update by giving not all primary keys in casssandra database?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have an application which using cassandra as database. and the row of the table filled by three separate moments (by three inputs) ,  I have four primary keys in that table and these primary keys not available at all the moment going to insert or update.

the error  is:

```
Some partition key parts are missing' when trying to insert or update.
```

Please consider that my application have to a lot of (near 300,000) writes in to database in a short time of interval , so i want to consider the maximum writes available in db.

May be it is a criteria can solve the issue ,'first read from db then write into db and use dummy values for primary key if it is not available at the moment of inserting or updating' . But it will take place more activities about a another copy of 300,000 reads in the db and it will slow the entire processes of db and my application.
So i looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

> four primary keys in that table and these primary keys not available at all the moment going to insert or update.

As you are finding out, that is not possible.  For partition keys in particular, they are used (hashed) to determine which node in the cluster is primarily responsible for the data.  As it is a fundamental part of the Cassandra write path, it *must* be complete at write-time and cannot be changed/updated later.

The same is true with clustering keys (keys which determine the on-disk sort order of all data within a partition).  Omitting one or more will yield this message:

```
Some clustering keys are missing
```

Unfortunately, there isn't a good way around this.  A row's keys must all be known before writing.  It's worth mentioning that keys in Cassandra are unique, so any attempt to update them will result in a new row.

Perhaps writing the data to a streaming topic or message broker (like Pulsar or Kafka) beforehand would be a better option?  Then, once all keys are known, the data (message) can consumed from the topic and written to Cassandra.